# After running vba on one sheet, it jumps to another sheet automatically

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

After pressing "F5" to run all the codes on sheet1 of workbook1, Macro window jumps to sheet2 of workbook2. Could anyone help explain it? Thank you!

Comment: Without seeing your macro, it would be pure guesswork to understand what is going on. I would look for a `Select` or `Activate` as the 1st thing to find

Comment: Please post your code if you want a definitive solution.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code, my shot in the dark guess is that some code in Workbook1 is invoking the `Application.Run` command to execute code in workbook2.  Or possibly just opening / activating the workbook2 window at sheet2 as Sean has mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason.
The sheet that was operated on (E in the case above) was originally hidden.

I added

```
E.visible = true
```

to unhide sheet E first, then problem went away.